# Removing a Pointer From Array using ObjectId

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Using Parse

I have an array of pointers, and I would like to remove an object from that array using only its objectId:

```
var rawProductObject = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
var product = new rawProductObject();
product.id = productObjectId;

userInventoryQuery = new Parse.Query("Inventory");
userInventoryQuery.equalTo("objectId", userInventory.id);

product.remove("owners", inventoryQuery)
```

However this does not work. I am not entirely sure about passing a query to the `remove` method, and not sure how to test it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you insist on using a framework for something that can be done with clean JS?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson I don't insist on anything. How are you going to remove a pointer from an array that you don't have locally, in clean JS?

Comment: I believe you would be the hypothetical one removing a pointer from an array..so I wouldn't, nor would I put myself in such a situation @ray to answer your question though, get a reference, iterate, check, remove

Comment: In the posted code, `product` just got created, so its `owners` array is undefined.  Even if it weren't, the thing the code tries to remove is `inventoryQuery`.  How is inventoryQuery defined?  Is it a query?

Comment: My question is why do you need an array of pointers ?? Isn't a Parse `Relation` really an array of pointers ??? Don't you think that is what you need instead ?